# How can I make diagonal shapes in C++?

Tags: c++

I currently have some problem with looping. Please help me to make some program that run like this :

[image: should be this]

But I have made some program that runs kind of like this :

[image: my own program]

And this is my code for my program. Maybe you can correct the wrong syntax.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input;
    char abjad;
    abjad='A';
    cout<<"INPUT = ";
    cin>>input;
for(int i=1;i<=input;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            cout<<abjad;
            abjad++;
        }
        cout<<i+1;

        for(int k=0;k<input-i-1;k++){
            cout<<abjad;
            abjad++;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to update the links or not done correctly, use [link name](paste link here)

Comment: This is not a C++ related issue. It is just an issue with the algorithm used to achieve desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
// ...

for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        cout << abjad;
        abjad++;
    }
    cout << i + 2;

// ...
```

I have only changed the first `for` loop to start with `0` instead of `1` and as a compensation to this the condition changed to `i < input` instead of `<=`. Also number output is now `cout << i + 2;`

This should fix your issue.